# Generating a loop counter in Ember.js #each

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js

I'm finding the restrictions of handlebar templates in Ember.js to be absolutely crippling.  You can't execute arbitrary javascript.  All you get is a fixed set of abilities (if/else, each, action, view, outlet) and the ability to output the value of a property on the current context object.

Which means I cannot figure out how to do something as simple as utilizing a loop counter in order to, for example, slap positional IDs on an html element inside a loop based on it's position in the collection I'm iterating on.

It doesn't make sense to add it as a computed property on the model, because that's not model-level knowledge (the same model could be in two different positions in different views).

FYI-Using Ember-1.0-pre, Ember-Data, and Rails with ActiveModel::Serializers on PostgreSQL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd recommend writing a handlebars helper, in which you can execute arbitrary javascript. See
http://handlebarsjs.com for some examples.

Alternatively, you could include the positional IDs on your child views (not your models).

Comment: I'll look into the first, and I don't quite understand what you mean by the second.

Comment: I mean that you could use views to represent each model in your collection. These could be iterated upon either within an {{each}} helper or using an Ember.CollectionView (see the itemViewClass property). These child views could obtain their positional IDs from the parent view.

Comment: Haven't checked out CollectionView yet, only View and ArrayController.  I'll see what I can do with it - thanks.

Answer (score 9):

With handlebars.js (v. 1.0.rc1) I could do this:

```
 {{#each links}}
   <li>{{@index}} - {{url}}</li>
 {{/each}}
```

Comment: My version is 1.0.0.rc.3 and when I add this I get an unexpected token error.

Comment: @Deli I'm also getting an "unexpected token ," -- did you solve the issue?

Comment: Works fine for me in handlebars 1.0.0, +1

Comment: If `{{@index}}` is not working for you, you may need to use `{{@key}}`. One is for a numbered array. The other is for object maps ("named arrays").

Answer (score 2):

Turns out providing a loop counter is the exact subject of the final example on this page:

http://handlebarsjs.com/block_helpers.html

(Dan G already pointed out the "writing a helper" solution in his answer, but since there's already a published example, I wanted to create a fresh answer to make the link more prominent.)