# How do you something n times in emberjs template?

Tags: loops, templates, ember.js, mustache

In ruby you can do

`3.times{puts "hello"}`

or

`(0...3).each{puts "hello"}`

and it will print hello 3 times.

How do I do this in an emberjs template?

Further more, is there a while or for loop (or something like them) that can be used in emberjs templates.  I know there is a `each` loop but I am looking form something that does not need a collection to start with.

Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Generating a loop counter in Ember.js #each](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12331780/generating-a-loop-counter-in-ember-js-each)

Comment: @Matt. So basically the way to print hello 3 times in emberjs template is to create a block_helper, implement a classic js for-loop and then call that block_helper from my template?  I guess with all the magic emberjs does I was expecting something this 'simple' to be handled by emberjs already like how they handle traversing collections in templates.  Either way, thanks.